# Pandas dataframe - Using np.clip() to set boundaires and subtracting values from a specific value in a column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas df and with `df['Battery capacity'] = np.clip(df['total_load'].cumsum() + 5200,-np.inf,5200)` I compute the values from "total_load" with the values from "Battery_capacity".

[image]

The problem which I cannot solve is, that for example at 14:00:00 "Battery capacity" is at 5200 but at 15:00:00 it doesn't substract the -221 from 5200 because it subtract from the value which is adding up in the background. I set the bounds to 5200 with np.clip()

So what I would like to have is something like:

```
time                total_load   battery capacity
2016-06-01 14:00:00   1980        5200
2016-06-01 15:00:00   -221        4979 (start subtracting from 5200) 
2016-06-01 16:00:00   -14.5       4964.5
```

How would I implement that into my code?

Thanks!

Comment: Please look at [How to Ask a Pandas Question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20159305/4909087).

Comment: Sry, i will do in future!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `np.clip` is computed after `np.cumsum` so by the time the sum gets to time `14:00:00` the sum is much greater than 5200 hence no subtraction.

I think looping may be the simplest way, however someone else may provide a better vectorized solution

```
val = 0
for index,row in df.iterrows():
    val = min(row['total_load']+val,5200)
    df.loc[index,'Battery capacity'] = val
```